# C - run into infinite loop when using .txt files as input

Tags: c, file-io, infinite-loop

I've just started learning C a month ago and this is a code I wrote for detecting the peaks of a list of data. It somehow runs into an infinite loop when I do "input data.txt" in terminal, but it works perfectly fine when I manually type in the exact same data via standard input aka keyboard. Any ideas why it runs into an infinite loop?

Thanks!

```
int main(void)
{
    int data1 = 0;
    int data2 = 0;
    int data3 = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &data1, &data2, &data3);
    puts("Number  Magnitude");

    while (data3!= EOF){
        if ((data1<=data2)&&(data2>data3)){
            printf("%*d%*d\n", 4,counter,11, data2);
            counter++;

        }
        data1 = data2;
        data2 = data3;
        scanf("%d", &data3);

     }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the input to the program in the case where you're not typing it in?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Note that if you run `./input data.txt`, your program is still reading from the keyboard, not from the file.  To read from the named file, you'd need to use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and then open the file.  You should probably try `./input <data.txt` as that sets the standard input to the named data file.  The other advice (about checking that your `scanf()` calls are successful) is also entirely valid.

Comment: I use"<input data.txt" in the terminal

Comment: If you use `<input data.txt`, then the input is coming from the file `input` and the program being run is `data.txt`.  Are you sure about what you said you're doing?

Comment: I just checked, scanf returns data1, data2, and data3 as 0,0,0, which being said that it's not scanning properly?

Comment: Don't you mean `input < data.txt`? That should behave as you described.

Comment: Just tested, input < data.txt returns the same data1,2,3 as when I do <input data.txt. Looks like the first scanf is not scanning the file, I printf data1,2,3 after each iteration and they're all 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

How are you stopping the input when trying it from stdin? With Ctrl-Z?

You need to test the returned result from your `scanf`:

> Return Value
>   On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.
>   (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Change the last line in your loop to

```
if (scanf("%d", &data3) < 1)
   break;
```

-- this also means that your `while` statement can be changed to

```
while (1) /* forever */
```

Comment: When using standard input I use ctrl-D cuz I'm in linux, or simply add a -1 (value of EOF) at the end of the data. 

I just checked that my scanf is not scanning the file properly, scanf returns 0, 0, 0 when I print the values of data1, data2, and data3.

In the case of multiple peaks in the data file, I don't think I could use break in my if statement?

Comment: The `break` there is to stop your program, when there is no more input. You need to figure out how to find your 'multiple peaks' before that. Can you give a list of valid data, with the multiple peaks marked?

Comment: Sure. 1 3 5 6 7 4 3 2 0 5 2 0. Expected to identify 7 and 5 as peaks.

Comment: Okay. It's as I thought, my `break` doesn't relate to this (next) problem. It seems your original problem is solved, so go ahead and try to implement this next step yourself. If you get stuck, post a new question. (Hint: what order of values makes it a *peak*?)

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", &data3);
```

above function's default input stream is redirected to

```
printf("%*d%*d\n", 4,counter,11, data2);
```

function's output.
you must distinguish it.

detail code is about this. just let the input function(fscanf) read numbers from a file is ok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int data1 = 0, data2 = 0, data3 = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    puts("Number Magnitude");

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    if(fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &data1, &data2) != EOF){
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &data3) != EOF) {
            if((data1 <= data2) && (data2 > data3)){
                printf("%*d%*d\n", 4, counter++, 11, data2);
            }
            data1 = data2;
            data2 = data3;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

output like this:

$ cat data.txt

3 3 4 5 5 5 4 2 1 191 3 43 2  3 0

$ ./a.out data.txt

Number Magnitude
   1          5
   2        191
   3         43
   4          3

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to distinguish it exactly? Sorry I'm pretty new to C

Comment: Thanks for the code, but my code will be tested by an online autotester so I won't be able to know what the input file is called, but I know that the input file will be readable by scanf & got told to test my code with .txt file

Comment: Just pass the file name to the a.out is ok

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused here but you're scanning in from the default input/output, likely the terminal, when using scanf, not a file. try creating a file pointer and using fscanf. for example

```
FILE *data;
data=fopen("data.txt", "r+");
fscanf(data,"%d",&data1);
fclose(data);
```

Comment: just noticed you're redefining the standard input so nvm. an infinite loop can be coming from your loop being dependent on data3 to exit. try doing an and statement and saying while data1,data2 and data3 are not eof.

Answer (score 0):

At first you're assigning values to `data1`, `data2`, `data3` and the you are asking for input values from the user also. Either you ask for an input value or you assign some definite values to those variables. Also in your while loop `EOF` is undefined, so change it to some value or to a proper condition.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I'm curious about why you think `EOF` is undefined — is it because the code doesn't show `#include <stdio.h>`? If so, then at one level you're correct, but people often omit the `#include` lines from questions when it's easy to guess which ones are included. It is easier if the code is an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), but adding one missing header is not too onerous. You're correct that initializing the `dataN` variables before using `scanf()` is redundant; however, it's not harmful.

Comment: Yeah I do have #include <stdio.h> in my code but I left it out of the question. I was told to always initialise variables so I assigned values to dataN. I found that the only problem I'm having is that my scanf doesn't scan any data from the file (data1,2,3 are always 0 hence infinite loop), but it does scan when I input data via standard input